# Prove $f(x) = \frac{Tx}{\|{Tx}\|}$ is continuous

Tags: continuity, metric-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $T$ be a square matrix $n \times n$ such that all entries are real and positive numbers. Let E = $\{(x_1, ... , x_n) \in \mathbb{R^n} : x_1 + ... + x_n = 1, x_1 \geq 0, ... , x_n \geq 0\}$.

Prove that:

$ \hspace{1cm} f: E \rightarrow E$

$\hspace{1.7cm} x \rightarrow f(x) := \dfrac{Tx}{\|{Tx}\|}$

is a continuous function.

I'm trying to prove this to use the Brouwer point fix theorem and prove matrices with real positive entries have at least one real positive eigenvalue. But i'm not able to do that. Any hints?

Comment: You're overthinking this. There's no need to use eigenvalues. All you need are two results: matrix multiplication is continuous, scalar multiplication is continuous, and the reciprocal function is continuous over its domain. Try to keep it simple.

Comment: Maybe i said the things in the wrong order (not a native english speaker haha), but i'm trying to use the continuity to prove a result of eigenvalues, not trying to use eigenvalues to prove the continuity. But thanks, with your's answer i can see what i was missing. I was just blind haha, really thanks.

Comment: $f$ is defined only on $E\setminus \text{ker} T$ as we cannot divide by $0$.